# "contar los 3 mayores" con pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un csv en donde de una categoría debo sacar las 3 mayores repeticiones, entonces me quedé en filtrar que solo sean 3. Adjunto código de lo que estoy haciendo para que se entienda mejor.

```
N=df["NATIVE.COUNTRY"].value_counts()
print(N)
```

Aquí me imprime todas las nacionalidades (en este caso) pero yo solo necesito las 3 primeras. ¿Algún consejo?
[image: csv]

https://www.mediafire.com/file/v476ejmdx8r35vz/titanic.csv/file

Comment: Ok, te podría ayudar pero no se cuales son tus datos, por favor muestra tus datos, el csv o el archivo con el que trabajes

Comment: @Christian ahí coloque una imagen bro

Comment: Imagen no, copia y pega los datos, como quieres que alguien re0lique eso?

Comment: @Christian ahí coloque un link para descargar el csv

Comment: Revisa el artículo sobre [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), recuerda que debes aportar un [ejemplo mínimo completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) o sea, que tu problema sea reproducible; no obligues a los demás a trabajar demás y como sugerencia, copia unas 10 líneas representativas de tu CSV y tenlas en la pregunta, no en sitios externos, esto para que en un futuro otras personas con la misma duda puedan comprender el problema fácilmente sin depender de si el link sigue existiendo o no.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debes haces es verificar la frecuencia de NATIVE.COUNTRY:

```
freq = df.groupby(['NATIVE.COUNTRY']).count()

print(freq)
```

Luego ordenas el resultado anterior:
colocas el ascending=False para que lo ordene de forma descendente

```
bynativecountry = freq.sort_values('AGE', ascending=False
print(bynativecountry)
```

y luego verás quienes son los tres máximos usando el método head()

```
maximos = binarycountry.head(3)
print(maximos)
```

Comment: por que ordenas en base a la edad?

Comment: se puede ordenar en base a cualquier columna, si te das cuenta, se ha creado un data frame donde el principal es el que el interesa al OP (NATIVE.COUNTRY)  ya lo que hace es contar cuantas veces aparece NATIVE.COUNTRY y por eso cada uno de los demás datos arroja el mismo resultado, pues está contando simplemente. Pero me gusta mucho más tu respuesta, ya le di mi voto.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma simplificada de hacerlo seria utilizar el método `apply()` del *Dataframe* y hacer el ordenamiento ahí, de esta forma nos ahorramos código y hacemos menos operaciones por separado.

```py
maximos = df.groupby("NATIVE.COUNTRY").count().apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False)) #ordenamos de forma descendente
print(maximos.iloc[:3]) #escogemos los 3 primeros
```

En el método `apply()` le pasamos una lambda y lo que hace es ordenar los datos de forma descendente, si quieres ordenar en base a un campo en especifico se lo puedes especificar `sort_values("campo",ascending=False)` si no lo especificas la función se encargara de hacer un ordenamiento *general*. con `iloc[]` escogemos las primeras 3 filas, esto es útil si luego quieres trabajar con estos u operar con ellos.

**resultado**

|  | AGE | WORKCLASS | FNLWGT | ... | CAPITAL.LOSS | HOURS.PER.WEEK | INCOME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NATIVE.COUNTRY | ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| United-States | 26232 | 26232 | 26232 | ... | 26232 | 26232 | 26232 |
| Mexico | 583 | 583 | 583 | ... | 583 | 583 | 583 |
| ? | 529 | 529 | 529 | ... | 529 | 529 | 529 |